# One function of my webpage has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, cors

One function of my webpage has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What should I do with this error, thanks?

Webpage code:

```
<html>        
<tr>
         <td id="Bot_trap"> 
           <script type="text/javascript"> botQuestion(); </script>
         </td> 
         <td>Answer: <input id="Answer_please" name="human_answer" type="text" size="3" 
                      title="So that we know you are not a bot."></td>
       </tr>

</html>
```

botQuestion() code:

```
function botQuestion() {
  var req = false;
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if( !req ) {
    return "I could not create an XMLHttpRequest object.";
  }
  
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200 ) {
      var question = req.responseText;
      showQuestion(question);
    }
  }
  
  urlInc = url_get_question;  
  req.open("GET", urlInc, true);
  req.send(null);
} // end botQuestion()


function showQuestion(question) {
  document.getElementById("Bot_trap").innerHTML 
    = "<b>What is " + question + "? *</b>";
} // end showQuestion()
```

Comment: _"What should I do with this error"_ - Search on SO. There will be a bunch of questions for that exact same error message including answers how to "fix" it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve data from another origin, the api server from that origin should have a special settings, allowing responses to be read from your desired origin. Otherwise you cannot have access to responses (in the browser).

The problem is related either to [Content Security Policy Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) or [access-control-allow-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) response header.
Read about them and you would be able to solve it.

Comment: This should be a comment